# How do I write SQL "Top 1" in PowerQuery?

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

How do I write SQL "Top 1" in PowerQuery?

```
Select Top 1 ObjectID, Name, StageEntryDate
From Table
Order By StageEntryDate Desc
```

This doesn't work

```
   ....
   #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"ObjectID"}, {{"Dated", each List.Max([StageEntryDate]), type datetime}, {"StagedAsID", each List.Max([ObjectID]), type text}}),
   ....
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Let me try rephrase that properly.

How do I select the last name in each group, based on date, using PowerQuery?

SampleData

```
|GroupID|ObjectID|Name      |StageEntryDate|
|-------|--------|----------|--------------|
|1      |       1|  Stage1  |2022-05-20    |
|1      |       2|  Stage2  |2018-07-26    |
|1      |       3|  Stage3  |2020-06-20    |
|2      |       4|  Stage1  |2018-05-18    |
|2      |       5|  Stage2  |2010-03-16    |
|2      |       6|  Stage3  |2018-05-06    |
|2      |       7|  Stage4  |2025-03-27    |
|3      |       8|  Stage1  |2029-11-15    |
|3      |       9|  Stage2  |2012-12-24    |
|4      |      10|  Stage1  |2023-10-24    |
|4      |      11|  Stage2  |2023-01-17    |
|4      |      12|  Stage3  |2012-10-25    |
|4      |      13|  Stage4  |2011-02-19    |
|4      |      14|  Stage5  |2025-09-22    |
|4      |      15|  Stage6  |2025-08-28    |
|4      |      16|  Stage7  |2015-12-15    |
```

For each Group, I want the most recent 'Name' value (based on date)

So for GroupID=1 I want "Stage1"
GroupID = 4 I should get "Stage5"

Answer (score 0):

use Table.FirstN(table as table, countOrCondition as any) as table

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide an example, I'm not sure exactly what you want.

If you want the highest value entry from each of those columns, then your code looks like it should work.

If you want the first entry in the subtable, regardless of value, then maybe:

```
   #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"ObjectID"}, {
        {"Dated", each [StageEntryDate]{0}, type datetime}, 
        {"StagedAsID", each [ObjectID]{0}, type text}
        })
```

If you want something else, then please provide data sample as text and desired output as a screenshot.

***Edit:*** With your rephrased question, try:

```
//Group by ID, then extract the Name corresponding to the most recent StageEntryDate
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"GroupID"}, {
        {"Most Recent Name", each  [Name]{
            List.PositionOf([StageEntryDate], List.Max([StageEntryDate]))}}        
        })
```

Using your data:

[image]